# Rails list countries by region

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user table and I want to save user country and region information. I have currently have a form and I am using the following country select gem to list all the counties:

```
<%= country_select("user", "country", [ "United Kingdom", "France", "Germany"]) %>
```

but this only saves the country name on user table country column. I want to separate each user by region, but I don't have any idea, where to start. I have looked into

> https://github.com/hexorx/countries

this project. but I don't know how to figure this out. any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508903/worldwide-location-country-region-city-select-plugin-for-rails-jquery-or-go

Answer (score 0):

In the Countries gem go through fully. You will get answer definitely.

Here the code helps you

```
c = Country.find_country_by_name(params[:user][:country])
region = c.region
# save the user with the region
```